# Online compilers and repls - not one big security hole?

Tags: security, compiler

There are plenty of compilers and REPL services on the web. For example: [Fay ide](http://ide.fay-lang.org/).

I find that implementing some similar technology would be very interesting. But it seems like a major security hole. Am I wrong in thinking that exposing a compiler would be risky? An interpreter seems even worse.

**update:** I can be a bit more specific. The kind service I'm thinking about hosting myself (a thought experiment at this stage) would be kind of close to the case of the Fay ide above. You take input from the user, process it and return it, potentially as runable javascript to the same or other users. Let's look at that example in particular.

The most obvious security concern that I see for this case, as I don't actually evaluate the code server side, would be for the users, as they would run code made by an 'unknown' author. The fact that they are allowed to read the code before running it should be a significant safeguard in this regard.

Although I also wonder if and when translation of code constitute a threat to the server? What kind of exploit vectors could be thought of in this context?

**Summary:**

1. Beyond what you can expect from any web server set up, and beyond the most obvious concerns (or perhaps some of those obvious concerns as well), how could one user compromise another?
   -. How can the server application be hardened to ensure not being compromised?
2. What important questions have I neglected? ;)
3. I would like to try some experiments, and I have nearlyfreespeech in mind as a host. I could imagine that such use might be prohibited by their terms of use? Or perhaps I can trust them to be sure enough that they have sandboxed my account well enough. What should be my "minimum" safeguards, for trying stuff out and what safeguards would be possible with such limited hosting environment?

**update2:** I believe that compiling to javascript for client side evaluation or evaluating limited edsls would cover for most/all use cases I have in mind. I take it that this means that I really don't put the server side to a more prominent risk than *usual*. And I don't see how the user is being put into more risk than compared to going to a random link on jsFiddle.

Comment: Security hole for who? For the one *providing* it or for the one *using* it? What kinds of attacks are you expecting?

Comment: They absolutely 100% *can* be enormous security holes. Perhaps you meant to ask, *how does someone secure such a thing?* with the presumption that measures have been taken by those who do have online compilers/repls to ensure they are secure.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I think it's pretty obvious, the fear is that allowing anyone to write code which your server arbitrarily interprets to send back the results may allow someone to write code that when interpretted executes arbitrary code possibly raising the processes security level through a known vulnerability allowing who knows what kind of direct access by the rest of the script as it is interpreted. I don't think we need to think that hard to find the attack vectors the OP is concerned about.

Comment: So, @JimmyHoffa. Your standpoint is; 'don't go there, it's full of snakes'?

Comment: @worldsayshi no, I was just answering the question posed above of "What kind of attacks are you expecting", for those who didn't see the obvious attacks you were concerned about. I believe it can be secured to an extent for certain, very smart people have placed most of those repl/compilers online you're referring to, I'm sure they wouldn't do it if they didn't believe they could secure the process. Whether they were right or not? Well, nothing is ever really secure, but I wager you can get pretty solid results with appropriate VM sandboxing.

Answer (score 7):

If all you're doing is compiling code (taking the user's code and transforming it without actually running it), it's no different than securing any other online program.  You have a program (a compiler) that takes potentially untrusted user input (the user's code) and does something with it, and you need to make sure that it doesn't do anything it shouldn't even when given malicious input.  For a compiler, many of the standard web security risks (SQL injection, CSRF) don't really apply, but you would need to check for risks like these:

- For language features like C's [#include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), make sure you don't permit including files outside of the standard library files.
- Some languages can take arbitrarily large CPU or memory to compile (thanks to features like C++'s [Turing-complete templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189172/25507)), so you need to guard against denial of service.  However, operating systems and web servers have long had features to terminate processes that take too long or grow too large.

If you're interpreting and running the user's code, then security requires running the user code in a sandbox of some sort.  For example, if you disable all library calls that involve file or network I/O and similar operating system calls, and if you have the aforementioned limits on CPU and memory, then in theory, the user code can't do anything bad.  In practice, this can be very tricky to get right.  For example, Python lets you easily execute code with restricted globals (so you can restrict the `os` module), but builtin language features and introspection still provide enough functionality to break out of the sandbox.  (See [here](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).)

Another approach to securing an online interpreter or REPL is to execute everything client-side (using JavaScript and, possibly, tools like [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten).  If the user code executes on the user's machine, then malicious user code isn't really your problem.

**Update:** As @JimmyHoffa points out, another approach is to use the OS or VM software to provide a more complete sandbox than the programming language is designed to do itself.  For examples of this, see [Chromium's sandbox for Windows](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox) or [various Linux options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249228/25507).

Comment: You refer to manual sandboxing, but there are sandboxing techniques provided by modern OS's that are much closer to executing in a VM where any IO facilities would be denied by the VM kernel which has no such facilities available to it, only memory and cpu access and only to it's own alotted memory block at that, beyond that range the kernel would treat like any kernel does when you request a memory block that doesn't exist.

Comment: Great info! Compiling to javascript (for client evaluation) or evaluating a limited custom embedded language would probably cover for most of the cases I have in mind. So sandboxing might not be necessary then? I'm thinking about running experiments (if and when I believe that I have confidence in doing so) in a limited host environment, such as an account at almostfreespeech. In such environment I would guess that my options for sandboxing, if needed, would be limited. *More in added description*